# how to save deepai output blob to file using let and async

Tags: javascript, image, asynchronous

Im using deep AI API to make an image a cartoon and it renders but now I need to save the image so it can be downloaded, I looked on stack overflow all over and cant find the answer, (they all use get method).

Also tyried let Blob=await response.blob();
it didnt work it stopped the render in fact!

```
(async function() {
   let result=await deepai.callStandardApi("toonify", {
    image: "<?php echo $url;?>"
});

let response=await deepai.renderResultIntoElement(result, document.getElementById('RES'));
let blob=response.blob();
//var file=new Blob(blob, {type:'image/jpeg'});

})();
saveAs(blob, "image/jpeg", "image.jpeg");
```

Its nearly there its trying to download to a file but it is saying not correct format upon opening. any ideas?

Getting error in console Uncaught TypeError: File constructor: Argument 1 can't be converted to a sequence.

Comment: oh, now that you've changed the code I see a problem ... `result` is not in scope, so who knows what it is, and you aren't waiting waiting for that async IIFE to complete anyway

Comment: Response.blob() is also async, add await before it, and move the saveAs call inside that IIFE, currently `blob` is undefined in its scope.

Comment: can someone fix it please I have no clue how to make it in scope? please post a pastebin link or something  can try out i would appreciate it and learn a lot from seeing what im doing wrong and what to do.???